# Plot plotly boxplots in subplots using for loop

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I have a Dataframe (df). I want to plot boxplot of each of the columns, and that these are displayed as subplots. However, the following code gives an error.

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

fig = make_subplots(rows = 5, cols = 2)
for i, column in enumerate(df.select_dtypes(include = np.number).columns.tolist()):
    fig.add_trace(px.box(df, y = [column]), row = i%5, col = i//5)
    fig.update_layout(width = 800, height = 800)
    fig.show()
```

Error: "----> 5     fig.add_trace(px.box(df, y = [column]), row = i%5, col =i//5)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my end your code snippet triggers:

> The 'data' property is a tuple of trace instances that may be
> specified as:
>
> - A list or tuple of trace instances
>   (e.g. [Scatter(...), Bar(...)])
> - A single trace instance

This is because `fig.add_trace` is designed to take `trace objects` as inputs, such as [`go.Box`](https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#box-plot-with-gobox), and not `figure objects` which is what will be returned by `px.box` that you are using here. So instead of that, you can use something like:

```
# plotly setup
plot_rows=6
plot_cols=6
fig = make_subplots(rows=plot_rows, cols=plot_cols)

# add traces
x = 0
for i in range(1, plot_rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, plot_cols + 1):
        #print(str(i)+ ', ' + str(j))
        fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df[df.columns[x]].values,
                                 name = df.columns[x],
                            ),
                     row=i,
                     col=j)

        x=x+1
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
## imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
np.random.seed(123)
frame_rows = 10
n_plots = 36
frame_columns = ['B_'+str(e) for e in list(range(n_plots+1))]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(frame_rows, len(frame_columns))),
                  index=pd.date_range('1/1/2020', periods=frame_rows),
                    columns=frame_columns)
df=df.cumsum()+100
df.iloc[0]=100

# plotly setup
plot_rows=6
plot_cols=6
fig = make_subplots(rows=plot_rows, cols=plot_cols)

# add traces
x = 0
for i in range(1, plot_rows + 1):
    for j in range(1, plot_cols + 1):
        #print(str(i)+ ', ' + str(j))
        fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=df[df.columns[x]].values,
                                 name = df.columns[x],
                            ),
                     row=i,
                     col=j)

        x=x+1

# Format and show fig
fig.update_layout(height=1200, width=1200)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I understand. I tried that because I did not find a solution on the internet. If you have any ideas on how to subplot px.box, please let me know, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure! I'll extend my original suggestion

Comment: Thank you very much, I managed to adapt it to my code!!  =)